# my pandas dataframe is not filterable by a column condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to only show rows where values in column A are greater than 0. I applied the following code but I am not getting the right returned dataframe. Why?

```
in: df.info()
out: 
A  non-null int64
B  non-null int64

in:df['A']>0
out:
A   B
5   1
0   0
```

Obviously, the second row should NOT show. What is going on here?

Comment: `df[df['A']>0]`?

Comment: df.loc[df['A']>0]

Comment: Your output is strange it should be a True / False Series. Can you also post the original DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the condition it's actually a filter (aka mask or predicate). You can take that filter and apply it to the DataFrame to get the actual rows:

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [2]: df = DataFrame({'A': range(5), 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  3  d
4  4  e

In [4]: df['A'] > 2
Out[4]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

In [5]: df[df['A'] > 2]
Out[5]:
   A  B
3  3  d
4  4  e
```

Another way to do the same thing is to use `query()`:

```
In [6]: df.query('A > 2')
Out[6]:
   A  B
3  3  d
4  4  e
```